# PHP : chdir('../') not working from command line

Tags: php, shell, command-line, chdir

I'm developing a PHP cron script to check if a server is up or not (Ping).

Here is my code :

```
// Remonte d'un dossier
chdir('../');

// Inclusion du header pour avoir les infos de connexion à la db, fonctions, etc ...
require_once('./includes/header.php');

// Requête pour récupérer toutes les IP à pinger (Non-exclues donc)
$sReqGetAllServers = "  SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            host
                        WHERE
                            exclude_machine = :exclude_machine";

// Préparation de la requête
$oDatabase->Prepare($sReqGetAllServers);

// On bind la valeur au paramètre dans le WHERE
$oDatabase->BindValue(':exclude_machine', 'n', PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Exécution de la requête
$oDatabase->Execute();

// On associe les données dans un tableau à deux dimensions associatif
$aServers = $oDatabase->Assoc();
```

So at the first line, I need to make a `chdir('../');` to include the necessary files (`header.php`).

I tested the script with Chrome and all worked fine but when I execute the script with command-line, PHP drop this error :

```
[14:40] root@dev.company.local / >> php -f /web/dev/company/public_html/dasPing/cron/cron.php 
PHP Warning:  require_once(./includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/dev/diadeis/public_html/dasPing/cron/cron.php on line 7

Warning: require_once(./includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/dev/diadeis/public_html/dasPing/cron/cron.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './includes/header.php' (include_path='/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/dev/diadeis/public_html/dasPing/cron/cron.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './includes/header.php' (include_path='/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/dev/diadeis/public_html/dasPing/cron/cron.php on line 7
```

I searched why PHP drop this but I can't find any answer.

Do anyone knows why this is happening ?

Thank you !!

Comment: chdir is working, but because you execute the script from the `/` directory, it will chdir to `/../`, what is `/`, execute your script like this:

`cd /web/dev/company/public_html/dasPing/cron/; php -f cron.php`

Comment: Try `chdir(__DIR__.'/../');` - to start from script directory.

Comment: Oooooooh ok ! I understand now. I will try to automate this part to `cd` the good folder. Thank you !

Comment: .. or just modify the 'require' argument, using `dirname(__FILE__)` as a prefix.

Comment: The difference stems from the PHP binary used. Newer PHP-CLI installments imply `-C`, whereas the older PHP-CGI alike versions switched to the scripts´ basedir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current working directory would be where you are executing the script from, not where the script lives.  You can get the directory that contains the script using the constant `__DIR__`

```
chdir(__DIR__ . '/../');
```

Comment: I forgot to flag your answer as my final answer. Thank you !